# Transferring a variable from one file to another

Tags: shell-script, variable

I have two files, config and template, and I want replace parts of the template with variables from config:

config.txt contains:

```
MYURL='www.google.com'
```

template.txt contains:

```
url = MYURL
```

I used

```
sed -e "s/MYURL/${replace}$MYURL/" template
```

But the variables of config.txt are only defined within that file. I also tried using

```
source config.txt
echo $MYURL
```

But it did not do what I wanted. How could I do this?

Comment: what did it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments just to show why I'd use grep later:

```
$ cat config.txt
/* blah blah yadda yadda */
/* look at me... I'm a text file, not a bash script... don't source me directly */
#MYURL='www.google.com'
MYURL='www.stackexchange.com'

$ cat template.txt
#url = example
url = MYURL
```

And the script:

```
$ source <(grep -E "^[0-9A-Za-z]+=" config.txt) 
$ echo $MYURL 
www.stackexchange.com
$ sed -r -e "s/^url[ ]*=.*/url=${MYURL}/" template.txt 
#url = example
url=www.stackexchange.com
```

(btw I have no idea what the intention of your sed script was... mine has a totally different approach, and supports both with or without whitespace in the template url=... and url = ..., but you can't have whitespace in config.txt or  you can't source it... without adding sed again to my grep)

edit: oh I guess wha tyou wanted was replace by dummy value instead of key, which if you prefer is simply:

```
$ sed -r -e "s/MYURL/${MYURL}/" template.txt 
#url = example
url = www.stackexchange.com
```

Comment: I'm unable to run this command. After adding: $ source <(grep -E "^[0-9A-Za-z]+=" config.txt) $ echo $MYURL a white space is returned

Comment: Are you using bash? Did you test with my input files? What is the exact content of your input file? And did you remove the $ which was just to show I'm running it in a shell showing what is commands and what is output?